# Kohana ORM subquery

Tags: php, orm, kohana

Can this statement be written as ORM in Kohana? There are a couple other questions related to this, but they don't seem to apply to my case.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT conversation_id, message, time_sent FROM messages ORDER BY time_sent DESC
) AS t1
GROUP BY conversation_id
ORDER BY time_sent DESC
```

I've got the two pieces separated, I'm just not sure how to combine them.

```
$sub = ORM::factory('messagesdb')
    ->order_by('time_sent', 'desc');

$result = ORM::factory('messagesdb')
    ->group_by('conversation_id')
    ->order_by('time_sent', 'desc')
    ->find_all();
```

I suppose I could use a join, but I'm not sure how to cross reference these two result sets.

Comment: Why do you need the subquery? As far as I can tell you don't need it.

Comment: What this does is select the most recent messages grouped by the conversation_id column. Using GROUP BY and ORDER BY in the same query doesn't return what you want, as the ordering happens after grouping.